# How do I get a fold/crease out of a car floor mat?

Tags: toyota, camry, interior

My passenger side (front) car mart has a strong crease.

Over the past 14 months I have tried a variety of things :

- Leave it flat out in the sun.
- Placed it flat out in the sun with three bricks on it. At the ends and on the crease.
- Just stood on the crease for some time.

I clearly don't understand how I can get rid of this crease.
What can I do to flatten this mat out? Its the OEM camry mat, if it matters.
[image: This is the car mat]

Comment: have you tried ironing it out  with a steam iron?

Comment: If you have a shower, hang it up in the bathroom for a few days.  Each time you use the shower and the room gets steamed up, the crease will become less and less.

Comment: is it plastic backed?

Comment: I get that too. I think now it's because of my foot movement. Unconsiously, I think I when I move my foot forwards, it tends to scrape against the mat slowly pushing the mat forward and creating the crease :)

Comment: I bought a 3M replacment mat, the kind that traps dirt... It's more robust than the OEM. Problem solved :)